# create a function ved that will only remove the last occurrence of the largest item in the list using recursion

Tags: haskell

You must use recursion to define rmax2 and you must do so from “scratch”. That is, other than the cons operator, head, tail, and comparisons, you should not use any functions from the Haskell library.

I created a function that removes all instances of the largest item, using list comprehension. How do I remove the last instance of the largest number using recursion?

```hs
ved :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
ved [] =[]
ved as = [ a | a <- as, m /= a ]
  where m= maximum as
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to split the problem into two easier subproblems consists in:

1. get the position index of the rightmost maximum value
2. write a general purpose function `del` that eliminates the element of a list at a given position. This does not require an `Ord` constraint.

If we were permitted to use regular library functions, `ved` could be written like this:

```
ved0 :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
ved0  [] = []
ved0 (x:xs) =
    let
        (maxVal,maxPos) = maximum (zip (x:xs) [0..])
        del k ys        = let (ys0,ys1) = splitAt k ys  in  (ys0 ++ tail ys1)
    in
        del maxPos (x:xs)
```

where the pairs produced by `zip` are *lexicographically* ordered, thus ensuring the rightmost maximum gets picked.

We need to replace the library functions by manual recursion.

Regarding step 1, that is finding the position of the rightmost maximum, as is commonly done, we can use a recursive stepping function and a wrapper above it.

The recursive step function takes as arguments the whole context of the computation, that is:

1. current candidate for maximum value, `mxv`
2. current rightmost position of maximum value, `mxp`
3. current depth into the original list, `d`
4. rest of original list, `xs`

and it returns a pair: (currentMaxValue, currentMaxPos)

```
-- recursive stepping function:
findMax :: Ord a => a -> Int -> Int -> [a] -> (a, Int)
findMax mxv mxp d  []    = (mxv,mxp)
findMax mxv mxp d (x:xs) = if (x >= mxv) then  (findMax x d (d+1) xs)
                                         else  (findMax mxv mxp (d+1) xs)

-- top wrapper:
lastMaxPos :: Ord a => [a] -> Int
lastMaxPos  []    = (-1)
lastMaxPos (x:xs) = snd (findMax x 0 1 xs)
```

Step 2, eliminating the list element at position `k`, can be handled in very similar fashion:

```
-- recursive stepping function:
del1 :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
del1 k d  []    = []
del1 k d (x:xs) = if (d==k)  then  xs  else  x : del1 k (d+1) xs

-- top wrapper:
del :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
del k xs = del1 k 0 xs
```

### Putting it all together:

We are now able to write our final recursion-based version of `ved`. For simplicity, we inline the content of wrapper functions instead of calling them.

```
-- ensure we're only using authorized functionality:
{-#  LANGUAGE  NoImplicitPrelude    #-}
import Prelude (Ord, Eq, (==), (>=), (+), ($), head, tail,
                IO, putStrLn, show, (++))  -- for testing only


ved :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
ved  []    = []
ved (x:xs) =
    let
        findMax mxv mxp d  []    = (mxv,mxp)
        findMax mxv mxp d (y:ys) = if (y >= mxv) then  (findMax y d (d+1) ys)
                                                 else  (findMax mxv mxp (d+1) ys)
        (maxVal,maxPos) = findMax x 0 1 xs
        del1 k d (y:ys) = if (d==k)  then  ys  else  y : del1 k (d+1) ys
        del1 k d  []    = []
    in
        del1 maxPos 0 (x:xs)


main :: IO ()
main = do
    let  xs  = [1,2,3,7,3,2,1,7,3,5,7,5,4,3]
         res = ved xs
    putStrLn $ "input=" ++ (show xs) ++ "\n" ++ "  res=" ++ (show res)
```

Comment: nice idea about the zipping and letting the lexicographic ordering do the work for you. :) (of course with manual recursion it's back to you doing the hard work :) ). few remarks: you don't use `maxVal`, so it needn't get a name. instead of returning the tuple from the base case of `findMax`, why not call the `del1` from there right away. it'll be a tail call. the top call would thus need to be changed to be the call to `findMax`. also, it can be `ved xs@(_:_) = ...`

Comment: @WillNess - Many thanks for the feedback. Technically, you're right on all counts, and I actually wrote myself a solution calling del1 directly. However, I hope you won't mind if I stick to somewhat *pedestrian* code here, given it is an elementary question, not something about Template Haskell or software transactional memory. I am not even sure it was such a good idea for me to short-circuit the "wrapper" functions. Some interested readers might be students who have not been introduced yet to the mysteries of @ and _ in Haskell syntax.

Comment: I hope I haven't offended you in any way, that wasn't the intention at all anyway. about the `x:xs`, I assumed you used it to prevent warnings, but the (never former) Lisper in me is wired to avoid re-consing what was previously de-consed, hence the suggestion. :) (simple `xs` would be perfect, except for the possible compiler warnings, or the possible warnings from other SO users about the compiler warnings.)

Comment: @WillNess - no, I did not feel offended at all. I understand your concerns, but I was just trying to keep my code easy to understand for a beginning Haskeller, its intended readership. After all, SO question 30326249 just asks what does @ mean in Haskell; its poster could not find the info thru web searches :-( Also it seems to me that replacing a variable name by _ can sometimes obscure the code. Maybe something like xs@(_) would be better. I don't suppose that the use of _ improves code efficiency, as the compiler can readily see that the variable is unused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are strictly required to use recursion, you can use 2 helper functions: One to reverse the list and the second to remove the first largest while reversing the reversed list.

This result in a list where the last occurrence of the largest element is removed.

We also use a boolean flag to make sure we don't remove more than one element.

This is ugly code and I really don't like it. A way to make things cleaner would be to move the reversal of the list to a helper function outside of the current function so that there is only one helper function to the main function. Another way is to use the built-in `reverse` function and use recursion only for the removal.

```hs
removeLastLargest :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
removeLastLargest xs = go (maximum xs) [] xs where
  go n xs []     = go' n True [] xs
  go n xs (y:ys) = go n (y:xs) ys
  go' n f xs []  = xs
  go' n f xs (y:ys)
    | f && y == n = go' n False xs ys
    | otherwise   = go' n f (y:xs) ys
```

Comment: Your way removes all the largest numbers, not removing the last one.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I will work on it. I am grateful

Comment: You are right @Z-Y.L I didn't understand clearly that OP wants only the last element removed. I thought they had problem to remove the last element and the rest using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the implementation of [dropWhileEnd](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/Data-OldList.html#dropWhileEnd) from Hackage, we can implement a helper function `splitWhileEnd`:

```hs
splitWhileEnd :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitWhileEnd p = foldr (\x (xs, ys) -> if p x && null xs then ([], x:ys) else (x:xs, ys)) ([],[])
```

`splitWhileEnd` splits a list according to a predictor from the end. For example:

```hs
ghci> xs = [1,2,3,4,3,2,4,3,2]
ghci> splitWhileEnd (< maximum xs) xs
([1,2,3,4,3,2,4],[3,2])
```

With this helper function, you can write `ven` as:

```hs
ven :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
ven xs = 
    let (x, y) = splitWhileEnd (< maximum xs) xs
     in init x ++ y

ghci> ven xs
[1,2,3,4,3,2,3,2]
```

For your case, you can refactor `splitWhileEnd` as:

```hs
fun p = \x (xs, ys) -> if p x && null xs then ([], x:ys) else (x:xs, ys)
splitWhileEnd' p [] = ([], [])
splitWhileEnd' p (x : xs) = fun p x (splitWhileEnd' p xs)

ven' xs = let (x, y) = splitWhileEnd' (< maximum xs) xs in init x ++ y
```

If `init` and `++` are not allowed, you can implement them manually. It's easy!

BTW, I guess this may be your homework for Haskell course. I think it's ridiculous if your teacher gives the limitations. Who is programming from scratch nowadays?

Anyway, you can always work around this kind of limitations by reimplementing the built-in function manually. Good luck!